# Emulator can not open locally saved html file - Access denied error

Tags: android, emulation, appium

I'm writing UI automation scripts for which need to load a static html page stored on my PC; onto a emulator.

When I try to access this directly from chrome browser in emulator with URL

file:////Users/me/Documents/workspace/sample-code/sample-code/apps/RottenTomatoesSnapshot.html

Access to the file was denied.

code I'm trying to execute

if (driver != null)
            driver.get("file:///" + new File(System.getProperty("user.dir").split("examples")[0]+"apps/RottenTomatoesSnapshot.html").toString());

Please clarify how to make this work

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulators don't access files on your hard drive, they access files in the emulator.  The easiest way to fix it is to add that file as an asset to your APK, and read it from assets instead.